# AIX Environment - TCP Port RecvQ data increasing but application not consuming

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, aix

Im new to the kernel level settings or TCP programming. So please bear with the basic (sometimes dumb) questions.

I have a scenario where in a client application connects to my server through a TCP port and sends messages.
My server application is hosted in AIX envi (java in WAS). I can successfully make connections to the server port but the message sent, is not consumed by the application.

The Netstat -an on the port shows increase in the recq data buffer size. but the application code is not triggered.

Im assuming the kernel which invokes the process waiting on this port, is not invoking it.

Please provide me with suggestions to check resolve the issue.

Comment: You'll need to provide some source code with that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is I do not have the client application. the server port is a tcp endpoint opened through camel. The system has been working till a few days back. The current situation in the port, I cud still see some connections in established state, though the IP is no longer existing. I had my suspicions on the firewall settings which could have been changed in the server.

Comment: If you can't provide source code it isn't a programming question and is therefore off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

What level of AIX?

There is a bug three plus years ago where select was being missed.  This was specific to pollset but that is probably what Java is using for its select.  While there is a small chance you are hitting that bug it is far more likely that the application is not working properly.

If you can find which thread should be reading from the socket, do a kernel trace of that thread.  If not, do a kernel trace of the whole process.  That will probably be very intimidating to plow through but that's where to start.  Utopia perhaps would be to do the kernel trace of the process while it is working to determine which thread(s) read from the socket.  Then when the problem happens, do a kernel trace of that thread.  You will likely find it locked out of a resource it needs by another thread which would create the question "why is that thread blocked?"  The chase will have begun.

There is also a script on a public IBM FTP server somewhere called pdump.  You can run pdump on the process during the non-working state to get the stack of each thread.  Especially if you know which thread(s) should be reading from the socket, this will help tell you what the reading threads are doing when the problem is happening.

lsof can help you figure out which file descriptor the socket is open on.  This will help you read both the kernel trace as well as the pdump information.  It is not "stock" AIX but is on the expansion packs.  fuser *can* do the same but I trust lsof more.

Good luck